# Percentage Calculations Not Working

Tags: python, calculator, percentage

```
mark=input("Please enter the mark you received for the test:")
total=input("Please enter the mark the test was out of:")

percentage=(mark*100/total)

print("Your percentage is:"),percentage,"%"
```

When I run this in python 3.3.2 mac it comes up with this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user1/Desktop/Percentage2.py", line 4, in <module>
    percentage=(mark/total*100)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Not any expert on Python, but the error clearly states that you cant use string in a math calculation. Change your variables to a numerical type, or convert them to a numerical type.

Answer (score 6):

```
percentage=(float(mark)*100/float(total))

print("Your percentage is: ",percentage,"%", sep='')
```

Answer (score 3):

An input returns a string, You are trying to do "30"*100/total, Strings cannot be mathematically calculated, try int(mark) and int(total) and then do the maths.

```
try:
    Mark = int(input("Please enter the mark you received for the test."))
    Total = int(input("Please enter the mark the test was out of."))
    Perc = (Mark*100) / Total
    print("Your Percentage is"+Perc)
except:
    print("Numbers not entered. Please try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make "print" statement do :

```
print ("your percentage is: %p" % (percentage))
```

Additionally you can use format :

```
print("your percentage is: {0} ".format(percentage))
```

Personally recommend  to use format.